# Define strong solution

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be open bounded. We find a function $u:\overline\Omega \rightarrow R$ satisfying $-\Delta u + u = f$ in $\Omega$, $u=0$ on $\partial\Omega$ ---(*)

Define strong solution (classical solution) of (*) in an appropriate Banach space.

Answer (score 5):

*Strong* and *classical* are not the same. Classical should be clear: a point-wise solution of the equation, and therefore a function $u$ of class (at least) $C^2$ that satisfies (*) at each point of $\Omega$.

A strong solution is something different, at least in principle: it is usually a twice *weakly* differentiable function $u$ that satisfies (*) almost everywhere. This is the definition in Gilbarg, Trudinger: Elliptic partial differential equations of second order, $2^{\mathrm{nd}}$ edition.

**Edit**: in particular, the concept of strong solutions is confined to *variational equations*. However, it seems that other Authors write *strong* to mean *classical*.

Comment: What about in evolution equations?