# What is weak and strong solutions in partial difference equation?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

In PDE, i learned that there are strong and weak solutions. 
What is their definition? and how they are related to each other?

Analytic and regularity seems relevant, but i am not sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the term "strong solution" see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/162353/define-strong-solution).

"Weak solutions" are usually solutions in the distributional sense, but see [this wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_solution) for a general discussion.